ggplot2 plot title based on other variable then the one used to iterate the loop
I would like to title each plot with an other variable then the one which is used to iterate the loop

My data




Id
Month
Day_available
Soil_type




Id 1
July
7
loam


Id 1
Aug.
5
loam


Id 1
Sept.
14
loam


Id 1
Oct.
12
loam


Id 2
July
7
clay


Id 2
Aug.
3
clay


Id 2
Sept.
6
clay


Id 2
Oct.
13
clay


Id 3
July
4
loam


Id 3
Aug.
9
loam


Id 3
Sept.
10
loam


Id 3
Oct.
4
loam


Id 4
July
10
sand


Id 4
Aug.
7
sand


Id 4
Sept.
12
sand


Id 4
Oct.
15
sand




My script

ID = unique(df$id)

for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
  df_i <- filter(df, id==ID[[i]])
  
  graph_i <- ggplot(data = subset(df_i))+ 
    geom_point(aes(Month,Day_available))+
    ggtitle(paste0("Day available at ", ID[[i]]," - ", ???))
  ggsave(paste0(ID[[i]], "_day_available.pdf"), plot=graph_i)
}

In the title I would like to have the Id (used to iterate the loop) and the Soil_type (note use no iterate the loop but present in the data frame).
Any suggestions ?
I tried this :
ID = unique(df$id)
SOIL = unique(df$Soil_type)

for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
  df_i <- filter(df, id==ID[[i]])
  
  graph_i <- ggplot(data = subset(df_i))+ 
    geom_point(aes(Month,Day_available))+
    ggtitle(paste0("Day available at ", ID[[i]]," - ", SOIL))
  ggsave(paste0(ID[[i]], "_day_available.pdf"), plot=graph_i)
}

I have the soil type in the title but it's always the same, not the one linked to my Id.

library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  id = c("Id 1", "Id 1", "Id 1", "Id 1", "Id 2",  "Id 2", "Id 2", "Id 2", 
    "Id 3", "Id 3", "Id 3", "Id 3", "Id 4", "Id 4", "Id 4", "Id 4"), 
  Month = c("July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", 
    "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct."), 
  Day_available = c(7, 5, 14, 12, 7, 3, 6, 13, 4, 9, 10, 4, 10, 7, 12, 15), 
  Soil_type = c("loam", "loam", "loam", "loam", "clay", "clay", "clay", "clay", 
    "loam", "loam", "loam", "loam", "sand", "sand", "sand", "sand"))

ID = unique(df$id)

for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
  df_i <- filter(df, id == ID[[i]])
  graph_i <- ggplot(data = subset(df_i))+ 
    geom_point(aes(Month,Day_available))+
    ggtitle(paste0("Day available at ", ID[[i]]," - " 
      , df_i$Soil_type[1]
      ))
  ggsave(paste0(ID[[i]], "_day_available.pdf"), plot=graph_i)
}


If you have any interest in a tidy solution you can nest the tibble so it only has 4 rows with 1 of the ID variables (IS and soil type) per row and the actual data in a nested dataframe
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

#From Michiel's answer
df <- tibble(
  id = c("Id 1", "Id 1", "Id 1", "Id 1", "Id 2",  "Id 2", "Id 2", "Id 2", 
         "Id 3", "Id 3", "Id 3", "Id 3", "Id 4", "Id 4", "Id 4", "Id 4"), 
  Month = c("July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", 
            "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct."), 
  Day_available = c(7, 5, 14, 12, 7, 3, 6, 13, 4, 9, 10, 4, 10, 7, 12, 15), 
  Soil_type = c("loam", "loam", "loam", "loam", "clay", "clay", "clay", "clay", 
                "loam", "loam", "loam", "loam", "sand", "sand", "sand", "sand"))


#nest the data.frame to get a 4 row dataframe instead
df_nest <- df %>% 
  nest(dat = c(Month, Day_available))



Then you can either loop through the 4 row dataframe
#for loop now each row is only 1 ID and soil type

for (i in 1:nrow(df_nest)) {
  df_i <- df_nest$dat[[i]]
  
  graph_i <- ggplot(data = df_i)+ 
    geom_point(aes(Month,Day_available))+
    ggtitle(paste0("Day available at ", df_nest$id[i]," - ",  df_nest$Soil_type[i]))
  ggsave(paste0(df_nest$id[i], "_day_available.pdf"), plot=graph_i)
}


or go full tidyverse and make the plot within the data.frame as well
#full tidyverse solution
df_nest <- df_nest %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(plot = list(ggplot(dat)+ 
           geom_point(aes(Month,Day_available))+
           ggtitle(paste0("Day available at ", id," - ", Soil_type ))))

#plots are in here if you want to view them interactively
# df_nest$plot

#use purrr::map to save using the ID from the first column for the file name and the plots from the plot column
 map2(df_nest$id, df_nest$plot, ~ggsave(paste0(.x, "_day_available.pdf"), plot=.y))



Created on 2024-07-26 with reprex v2.0.2
